# Determine the largest open set to which $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(2n+1)z^{n}$ can be analytically continued

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-continuation

Let $U=B_1(0)$ and $$f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{C},\qquad f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(2n+1)z^{n}.$$

Determine the largest open set to which $f$ can be analytically continued

**Remark:** I was given following suggestion: Consider $f(w^2)$.

Do not know how to use the suggestion, I would appreciate any suggestions in this exercise and if is possible, the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see to what sets $f$ can be analytically continued, it would help if we found a closed form expression for $f$. To do that, we use the hint and consider

$$g(w) := f(w^2) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^n (2n+1) w^{2n}.\tag{1}$$

Here, we recognise a derivative, which leads us to look at

$$G(w) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^n w^{2n+1} = \frac{-w^3}{1+w^2},\tag{2}$$

from which we find

$$g(w) = G'(w) = \frac{2w^4}{(1+w^2)^2} - \frac{3w^2}{1+w^2}.\tag{3}$$

Now set $z = w^2$ to find

$$f(z) = \frac{2z^2}{(1+z)^2} - \frac{3z}{1+z} = -\frac{z^2+3z}{(1+z)^2}.\tag{4}$$

In this form, it is easy to see that $f$ can be analytically continued to $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{-1\}$, and that that is the largest open set to which $f$ can be analytically continued.

Answer (score 0):

The series converges for $\;|z|<1\;$ , for example using the $\;n\,-$ th root test. Now, for any $\;|z|=1\implies z=e^{it}\;,\;\;t\in\Bbb R\;$ , we have that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}|(-1)^n(2n+1)e^{nit}|=\lim_{n\to\infty}(2n+1)=\infty\neq0$$

and thus the series doesn't converge on the unit circle, so the maximal open set where $\;f\;$ can exist as analytic function is the open unit disk $\;|z|<1\;$

Comment: The criteria you use is used in the real case, but: Is that criterion valid in the complex case?

Comment: joanpemo : are you sure you understand analytic continuation ? $f(z^2) = (\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n z^{2n+1})' = \left(\frac{z^{3} }{1+z^2}\right)' =  \frac{3z^{2} }{1+z^2} - \frac{2z^4 }{(1+z^2)^2}$ wich has poles at $z = \pm $i, hence $f(z^2)$ can be analytically continued to $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{i,-i\}$, hence $f(z)$ ..  (@DiegoFonseca)

Comment: @user1952009 Can I say that  $f(z) =  \frac{3z }{1+z} - \frac{2z^2 }{(1+z)^2}$ wich has poles at $z=1$?.

Comment: @DiegoFonseca : if $f(z)$ has its pole at $z=-1$ (and not $z=1$), then $f(z^2)$  has its poles at.. ?

Comment: @user1952009 $f(z^2)$ has its poles at $z = \pm i$.

Comment: @user1952009 Then, I can say that $f(z^2)$ can be analytically continued to $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{-1\}$.

Comment: @user1952009 Are you sure you understood what I meant? If a function has convergence radius $\;R\;$  but its power series doesn't converge at **any point** of $\;|zR\;$ then it cannot be continued *analitically* beyond $\;|z|<R\;$ (natural boundary) .  This is in the sense that **any** open domain $\;U\;$ that contains $\;|z|<R\;$ cannot possibly contain an *analytic* function on it that'll agree on $\;|z|<R\;$ with $\;f\;$ . Now, I can be wrong in my answer but this is, as far as I know, what is needed in *analytic*, as opposed to *continuous*, continuation

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you. I'm glad of your confirmation, yet I've no idea what is $\;P_0[f](z)\,,\,\,P_1/2[f](z)\;$ . I know, for example, that many analytic functions given by a power series with convergence radius $\;R\;$ (about any point, it doesn't matter now)  can be anal. continued *beyond* that radius, but I can't understand how can this achieved with a power series which *doesn't converge* for any $\;|z|=R\;$ . If therewas convergence in some arc or whatever then the cont. can be achieved by a path through that arc. Perhaps I'm wrong, but this is what I know and what imo says your link.

Comment: ( @Joanpemo : sorry maid a small mistake deleted the comment, I rewrite it)

Comment: @Joanpemo : yes I confirm you don't understand the analytic continuation. $P_0[f](z)$ the power series for $f(z)$ at $z=0$ doesn't converge on $|z|=1$, but $P_{i/2}[f](z)$ the power series at $z = i/2$ also has a radius of convergence $|i/2+1|$, hence you get the continuation to the whole circle $|z-i| < |i/2+1|$ which is not inside $|z| < 1$. continuating so one, from one disk where $f(z)$ is analytic  (holomorphic) to an another which is intersecting it, you have the analytic continuation of $f(z)$ to the whole complex plane except at $z = -1$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation
it is the fundamental tool of [complex analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_analysis), together with the [Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), it is for example how we can construct the Riemann zeta function and the Riemann hypothesis, or even  [the $\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Comment: The Riemann zeta function has one single singular point at $\;z=1\;$ , yet the function given by the series in the question has the whole circle $\;S^1\;$ as "natural boundary", meaning: it doesn't exist at any point there. This is something I'd like you to address. Thank you.

Comment: since with the power series at $z=0$ you can compute all the derivatives of $f(z)$  at $z=i/2$, you can build from that a power series for $f(z)$ at $z=i/2$.

Comment: and it is not because the series doesn't converge on $|z|=1$ that it cannot be extended by continuity on $|z| = 1$, take $g(z) = \frac{1}{1-z}$ to see how except at $z = 1$ the continuity defines without problem $g(z)$ and all its derivatives on $|z| = 1$

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you. Yes, I understand that...but what's its radius of convergence? If it is greater than $\;1/2\;$ and if it **really** is an anl. con. of our function, at some point on the unit circle that anal. cont. exist, yet ouf function doesn't...Is this what you're saying?

Comment: @joanpemo study a complex analysis course. $\frac{1}{1-z}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k$ are the same functions thanks to the concept of analytic continuation

Comment: @user1952009 Again: $\;g(z)=\frac1{z-1}\;$ has **only one singular** point at $\;z=1\;$ , not the whole circle! I'm sure I need to go over this stuff again since you seem to be very sure of this and I am not, yet

Comment: @Joanpemo : yes $\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k$ is analytic on $|z| = 1, z \ne 1$, hence it can be analytically continued outside the unit circle

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you for the advice and the continuous belittling. I think I'm going to stop this discussion now since you seem more interested in showing off and belittling than anything else. And no: I think that $\;\frac1{z-1}\;$ and $\;\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty z^n\;$ are the same function **only** when $\;|z|<1\;$ . Good day.

Comment: @Joanpemo : yes until now you THOUGHT it was two different functions, after reading a complex analysis course, you will think their analytic continuation are the same functions (what we always think to in complex analysis)